# Initializing BERT embeddings in a classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm quite new to TensorFlow and trying to do a multitask classification with BERT (I have done this with GloVe in another part of the project). My problem is with the concept of placeholder in TensorFlow. I know that it is just a placeholder of some variables and will be filled. See this is the part of my classification model that I have problem with. I'll explain the exact problem down here.

```
def bert_emb_lookup(input_ids):
    # TODO to be implemented;
    """
    X is the input IDs, but a placeholder
    """
    pass

class BertClassificationModel(object):
    def __init__(self, num_class, args):
        self.embedding_size = args.embedding_size
        self.num_layers = args.num_layers
        self.num_hidden = args.num_hidden

        self.input_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, args.max_document_len])
        self.Y1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
        self.Y2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
        self.dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [])

        self.input_len = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sign(self.input_ids), 1)

        with tf.name_scope("embedding"):
            self.input_emb = bert_emb_lookup(self.)
...
```

It was easy to get the word embeddings from GloVe; I first loaded the glove vectors and then simply used `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, self.input_ids)` to fetch the embeddings.

So in BERT classification model, I'm trying to do something similar by defining a function whose argument is `input_ids`, where I want to match input ids with their associated vocab (string). Thereafter, I'll use an API (BERT as a service) that gives BERT embeddings of any given list of strings at string-level/token-level. The problem is that since `self.input_ids` is just a placeholder, it shows it a NULL object. Is there any workaround that helps me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bert-as-service as a tensor directly. So you have two options:

1. Use bert-as-service to look up the embeddings. You give the sentences as input and get a numpy array of embeddings as ouput. You then feed the numpy array of embeddings to a placeholder `self.embeddings = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 768])`
   Then you use `self.embeddings` wherever you would have used `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, self.input_ids)`.
2. The other option is probably overkill in this case, but it may give you some context. Here you do not use bert-as-service to get embeddings. Instead, you use the bert model graph directly. You would use BertModel from https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_classifier.py to create a tensor which again can be used wherever you would use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, self.input_ids)`.